Do the old type of rubber hose Dunlop valves have any pros compared to the modern ones without rubber?
Do the old type of Dunlop valves with a small rubber hose have any pros compared to the newer, spring loaded ones?
So far, I’ve only come across cons, like that they dry out and are harder to inflate, but out of curiosity I wonder if they have some benefits?

Newer valve with spring to the left, older valve with rubber to the right.

Does it relate that Dunlop/Woods valves are generally only found in Europe and Japan?

I have played a fair bit with both types and the only pro that I could find with the older type is that there was a time where I could easily find and buy the tiny bit of rubber hose, so you could repair a leaky valve with quite a low effort. This isn't the case anymore since at least 25 years ago.
The modern ones are prone to clogging if you ride in dusty/muddy conditions without a valve cap, which is quite usual, as those caps are easy to lose and are prone to breaking and falling off. When dirt goes inside the valve it can prevent proper sealing. I used to clean those cores by putting them in the pump chuck while not installed in the tube and blowing air through it as hard as I could. It was not a reliable fix but could allow me to ride to the store and buy half a dozen cores for cheap.
The other common failure of the newer style is that with time, the little floating rubber piston that is inside could dry up and/or lose its shape, leading to a leaking valve. This was a not repairable failure, since it is very hard to open the little metal prongs at the end of the valve without breaking them, and even if you could, where would you find a replacement little rubber bit to fit there?
In that regard, the old type had the "pro" that could be easily cleaned and fixed.
The newer type is called "automatic" in my country. (Centro automático, Spanish for automatic centre or automatic core).
Inner tubes that accept dunlop valve cores are easily obtainable in my country, particularly for sizes like 281, 272, 26, 24, 20 and 16. Some of those sizes can be found even in hardware stores and general purpose stores, and are usually cheaper than presta valve tubes, particularly in rural areas, so, if I where bikepacking in my country or alike (3rd world, Latin America), I'd be sure that I'm using rims drilled for dunlop or schrader valves, and would carry a few valve cores, even if I had presta tubes, since a tube can be damaged beyond repair and the only option to buy could be of another valve type. In that line of tought: notice how the older dunlop have two prongs at either side. Those engage on corresponding slots in the tube, thus you can use modern cores on tubes with those slots, but not the other way around.
Comparing the two types, the newer one almost always has less resistance to air passage, thus allowing for quicker less tiring inflation when using manual pumps.
In conclusion: I would have no hesitation in buying a tube with the older style of dunlop valve, if that was the only option and the tube itself is in good condition, but I have no compelling reason to prefer one of those over the newer style, and of course, If there is a presta option available, I'd go for that instead.
Notes:
1: Size used for old city bikes, similar in size to 700x42c, but tires are not actually interchangeable, Inner tubes, however, can be used interchangeably.
2: Size for old road bikes, the same as above, similar to 700x25c. Not interchangeable for tires but very compatible for inner tubes.
